# How can I modify a string from a thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading

I am trying to modify a some strings from threads (each thread would have its own string) but all strings are stored in a vector, because i need to be able to access them after the threads have done their thing.

I haven't used threads in c++, so if this is a terrible thing to do, all suggestions welcome :)

Basically the only thing the program does now is:

- create some threads
- send a string and an id to each thread
- thread function modifies the string to add the id to it
- end

This gives a segfault :(

Is this just a bad approach? How else could I do this?

```
static const int cores = 8;

void bmh_t(std::string & resr, int tid){
    resr.append(std::to_string(tid));
    resr.append(",");
    return;
}        

std::vector<std::string> parbmh(std::string text, std::string pat){

    std::vector<std::string> distlists;
    std::thread t[cores]; 
    //Launch a group of threads
    for (int i = 0; i < cores; ++i) {
        distlists.push_back(" ");
        t[i] = std::thread(bmh_t,std::ref(distlists[i]), i);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < cores; ++i) {
        t[i].join();
    }

    return distlists;
}
```

Comment: Preallocate the vector<string>.  Pushback can, in most std libs will, resize and move the vector elements and that is not thread safe. Once the vector size is established it is thread safe.

Comment: Off topic: Take a look at `std::future`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your basic approach is fine. The main thing you need to consider when writing parallel code is that any data shared between threads is done so in a safe way. Because your algorithm uses a different string for each thread, it's a good approach.

The reason you're seeing a crash is because you're calling push_back on your vector of strings after you've already given each thread a reference to data stored within the vector. This is a problem because push_back needs to grow your vector, when its size reaches its capacity. That growth can invalidate the references that you've dispatched to each thread, causing them to write to freed memory.

The fix is very simple: just make sure ahead of time that your vector doesn't need to grow. This can be accomplished with a constructor argument specifying an initial number of elements; a call to reserve(); or a call to resize().

Here's an implementation that doesn't crash:

```
static const int cores = 8;

void bmh_t(std::string & resr, int tid){
    resr.append(std::to_string(tid));
    resr.append(",");
    return;
}

std::vector<std::string> parbmh(){

    std::vector<std::string> distlists;
    std::thread t[cores];
    distlists.reserve(cores);

    //Launch a group of threads
    for (int i = 0; i < cores; ++i) {
        distlists.push_back(" ");
        t[i] = std::thread(bmh_t, std::ref(distlists[i]), i);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < cores; ++i) {
        t[i].join();
    }

    return distlists;
}
```

Comment: Consider why you're using a vector too.  You could, for example, just use an array of strings since you need to presize the vector.

Comment: May be worth noting that alling `std::vector::resize()` with the current code won't work because `push_back`.

Comment: @Donnie arrays are fixed size though unless you allocate them dynamically and then you may as well use a vector (which does the same thing). Also returning an array is problematic.

Answer (score 1):

The vector of strings is being destructed before the threads can act on the contained strings. You'll want to [join](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/join) the threads before returning so that the vector of strings isn't destroyed.

Comment: "destructed"? The initial copy, maybe, but there is `return distlists;`, and what if OP wants to use the vector later, after `parbmh` returns?

I'm thinking there may be a bad design here, but is there enough information?

Comment: @Aaron Yes, there's enough information and the answer is correct.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ So, you know for sure that OP is not returning distlists because he plans on using it elsewhere, on the current thread, and that OP doesn't intend for the current thread to run while the spawned threads are executing? Perhaps he means it that way. Reading it from your point of view I suppose that makes more sense. It's not explicitly stated, but I suppose it is implied.

Comment: Well,, there are more problems, than just the missing join.The references may change as the vector is changed.

Comment: thank you! I forgot to join... but unfortunately that is not the problem, since it fails when threads are running. I believe it is the vector allocation issue, which I will look into

Comment: And there is the (unlikely these days) possibility that the returned `vector` will be copied, then destroyed. Nasty when stuff like that happens.